# Reporting spam or abuse via Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm using Telethon in python to automatic replies in Telegram's Group. I wanna reporting spam or abuse an account automatically via the Telethon and I read the Telethon document and google it, but I can't find any example.
If this can be done, please provide an example with a sample code.

Comment: I scanned the telegram API quickly, and couldn't find any public method for sending reports, presumably because this is abusable. Try watching to see the endpoint contacted when a report is sent.

Comment: @JammyDodger the methods are available for any MTProto client, see https://tl.telethon.dev?q=report&redirect=no.

Comment: @Lonami Ah that's a different list than I was looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One [can use search](https://tl.telethon.dev?q=report&redirect=no) to find the following report methods:

- [`messages.ReportRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/report.html) to report one or more messages.
- [`account.ReportPeerRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/account/report_peer.html) to report a user in private, chat or channel with a specific reason.
- [`messages.ReportSpamRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/report_spam.html) to report a user in private, chat or channel without a reason.
- [`channels.ReportSpamRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/report_spam.html) to report one or more messages of a user in a channel.

Comment: Why i am getting False when i use this function

Answer (score 4):

https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/report.html

Example from page:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.ReportRequest(
        peer='username',
        id=[42],
        reason=types.InputReportReasonSpam()
    ))
    print(result)
```